# What is the relationship of optical mode and data?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, research-level, fiber-optics, waveguide

This question is on the plot of mode division multiplexing system where it is said capacity crunch can be solved using mdm technique. Now, we know single mode fiber can transmit upto 1Tbps. Now if i use two mode then data transmission capability will be doubled? If the answer is yes, then why people are researching on more and more higher modes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole number of different aspects to consider. For starters, the two modes wouldn't experience the same dispersion, they would require different dimensions on the fiber core, something which can only be implemented in newer fibers. They would experience different phase-drift. The in-line amplifiers might not have the adequate gain for the second mode.

Basically, they behave in very different ways. Now, multimode systems do exist, but it is not a matter of simply putting in another mode, the whole system needs to be designed around this.

Comment: So, 2 mode does not mean that double capacity.And as i go further such as 3rd,4th,5th,6th mode that will not increase the capacity in same rate? But after all capacity will increase. Is it?

Comment: @HasanShuvo It has the potential to increase the capacity if the system is designed for it. If not, the 2nd mode may not have enoguh reach or may experience for dispersion than what can be compensated for etc, the phase may drift in another way than what the receiver is expecting etc.